# calico unable to ping other PODs created using calico network

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I setup to stateful pods running on 2 different worker node and I am unable to ping the pods. Following is the pool file:

```yaml
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: IPPool
metadata:
  name: rack.ippool-1
spec:
  cidr: 192.168.16.0/24 
  blockSize: 24  
  ipipMode: Never
  natOutgoing: true
  disabled: false
  nodeSelector: all()
```

IP config on 1st pod

```sh
ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3e:a6:cb:15:cf:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.16.41/32 brd 192.168.16.41 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3ca6:cbff:fe15:cf1a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

IP Conf on another node

```sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1a:3c:c1:1a:fa:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.16.42/32 brd 192.168.16.42 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::183c:c1ff:fe1a:fa03/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Ping Status

```sh
ping 192.168.16.41
PING 192.168.16.41 (192.168.16.41) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

It doesn't work.

I tried ipipMode: Always and CrossSubnet but nothing worked. I am not sure what I am missing. Also, I am not sure when I gave blocksize 24, why the IPs are in /32 CIDR. Aren't they in range of /24 CIDR?

```sh
[root@k8master-1 ~]# calicoctl node status
Calico process is running.

None of the BGP backend processes (BIRD or GoBGP) are running.
```

Calico IPam result

```sh
calicoctl ipam show
+----------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| GROUPING |      CIDR       | IPS TOTAL | IPS IN USE |   IPS FREE   |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| IP Pool  | 10.244.0.0/16   |     65536 | 1 (0%)     | 65535 (100%) |
| IP Pool  | 192.168.16.0/24 |       256 | 3 (1%)     | 253 (99%)    |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Calico ipam block

```sh
[root@k8master-1 ~]# calicoctl ipam show --show-blocks
+----------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| GROUPING |      CIDR       | IPS TOTAL | IPS IN USE |   IPS FREE   |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| IP Pool  | 10.244.0.0/16   |     65536 | 1 (0%)     | 65535 (100%) |
| Block    | 10.244.0.0/26   |        64 | 1 (2%)     | 63 (98%)     |
| IP Pool  | 192.168.16.0/24 |       256 | 3 (1%)     | 253 (99%)    |
| Block    | 192.168.16.0/24 |       256 | 3 (1%)     | 253 (99%)    |
+----------+-----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Calico's borrowed IP list

```sh
[root@k8master-1 ~]# calicoctl ipam show --show-borrowed
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------+--------------------+
|      IP       | BORROWING-NODE |      BLOCK      | BLOCK OWNER | TYPE |    ALLOCATED-TO    |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------+--------------------+
| 192.168.16.39 | k8worker-2     | 192.168.16.0/24 |             | pod  | default/racnode1-0 |
| 192.168.16.41 | k8worker-2     | 192.168.16.0/24 |             | pod  | default/racnode1-0 |
| 192.168.16.42 | k8worker-1     | 192.168.16.0/24 |             | pod  | default/racnode2-0 |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------+------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Where are you trying to ping from? Your machine, another pod, master node, etc?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to ping pod to pod at this moment. However, Would be great to know if we can ping the pod from the subnet of the master node and worker node cidr which is 10.0.1.0/24.

Comment: No, you can't ping from a node to a pod, that's why there are k8s services

Comment: What's the IP address range for your K8s nodes?

Comment: @Rico, thanks for providing input. As I mentioned I am looking for a solution to ping pod to pod when both the pods are on the same subnet. In my case both the pods are created using the calico network but on the different worker nodes. The pod subnet is 192.168.16.0/24.

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score -1):

I also having similar issue.  I created two pods nginx and busybox in same namespace, but I could not ping nginx pod from busybox with calico network plugin. If I expose as node port, I could connect to the pod from the node where the nginx pod is running.  If you try to hit the node port from  other k8 cluster node, it is not working.  I am still trying to find out why but no clue as of now.